# Evento slide.bs.carousel do carrossel não funciona

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slide

```js
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  alert("SLIDE");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">/script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="hover" onChange="test()">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" onclick="pauseYouTubeVideo()">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"  onclick="pauseYouTubeVideo()">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>  
</div>
```

Mas o evento não está funcionando, não é chamado o **alert** quando é feito o slide... Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Desde já, muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Você está chamando 2 versões do jQuery e também está fechando incorretamente uma das tags script.

Da seguinte forma irá funcionar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gabriel, valeu pela dica, mas não funcionou...

Answer (score 0):

Galera, achei meu problema e até peço desculpa!!! Como é a primeira vez que uso JQuery não sabia a estrutura, mas acabei descobrindo que:
EM VEZ DISSO:

```
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  alert("SLIDE");
})
```

O CORRETO É ISSO:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
        alert("SLIDE");
    })
});
```

Muito obrigado a quem tentou ajudar! Abraço!

Comment: Provavelmente não foi isso que resolveu. Observe e execute o código da minha resposta. A diferença de utilizar `$(document).ready()` é que você pode colocar o script antes de instanciar o carrossel - no cabeçalho, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Apesar de já ter resolvido, a solução que encontrei foi diferente:

- removi a segunda chamada do *jQuery*, ficando apenas a versão *3.3.1*;
- corrigi a chamada do *jQuery 3.3.1* que estava com o fechamento da tag `script` faltando um `<`:

  ```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">/script>
  ```

Execute o código e verá funcionando:

```js
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  alert("SLIDE");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000" data-pause="hover" onChange="test()">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <iframe id="testimony-video" class="youtube-video" type="text/html" height="400px" width="55%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytplayer&autoplay=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" onclick="return;">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="false"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"  onclick="return;">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Próximo</span>
  </a>  
</div>
```